# how to get page source dynamically to send by the email

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

can anybody help me how to get the page source of jsp page in (browser) into same jsp page (my code).so that i can send that page by email(outlook).

Send Mail

Comment: what do you mean by page ? just url or whole html content

Comment: i need whole html content

Answer (score 0):

You can use outerHTML on html element to get whole page html markup

```
 $('html')[0].outerHTML
```

or

```
document.querySelector('html').outerHTML
```

Comment: what's wrong with `document.firstElementChild.outerHTML` ?

Comment: The first is not possible in standard JavaScript. It requires jQuery. The question didn't anywhere mention that jQuery is being used.